# BigQuery dataset complete deleted/vanished

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've stored analytics in a BigQuery dataset, which I've been doing for over 1.5 years by now, and have hooked up DataStudio, etc and other tools to analyse the data. However, I very rarely look at this data. Now I logged in to check it, and it's just completely gone. No trace of the dataset, and no audit log anywhere showing what happened. I've tracked down when it disappeared via the billing history, and it seems that it mysteriously was deleted in November last year.

My question to the community is: Is there any hope that I can find out *what* happened? I'm thinking audit logs etc. Does BigQuery have any table-level logging? For how long does GCP store these things? I understand the data is probably deleted since it was last seen so long ago, I'm just trying to understand if we were hacked in some way.

I mean, ~1 TB of data can't just disappear without leaving any traces?

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant I'm not new to StackOverflow, the answer did unfortunately not help me as you stated, data retention period was out.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, [`Cloud Audit Logging`](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/) is used for this

> Cloud Audit Logging maintains two audit logs for each project and organization: Admin Activity and Data Access. Google Cloud Platform services write audit log entries to these logs to help you answer the questions of "who did what, where, and when?" within your Google Cloud Platform projects.
>
> Admin Activity logs contain log entries for API calls or other administrative actions that modify the configuration or metadata of resources. They are always enabled. There is no charge for your Admin Activity audit logs
>
> Data Access audit logs record API calls that create, modify, or read user-provided data. To view the logs, you must have the IAM roles Logging/Private Logs Viewer or Project/Owner. ... BigQuery Data Access logs are enabled by default and cannot be disabled. They do not count against your logs allotment and cannot result in extra logs charges.

*The problem for you is retention for Data Access logs - 30 days (Premium Tier) or 7 days (Basic Tier). Of course, for longer retention, you can export audit log entries and keep them for as long as you wish. So if you did not do this you lost these entries and your only way is to contact Support, I think*

Comment: is it possible to contact support for something like this without paying $150 for the "support" tier?